# How should I cite a reference from another document?

Tags: bibliographies

How should I cite a reference from another document? Now I am using the `xcite` package, then `\externalcitedocument{docname}`, and with the help of `\cite{}`, I cite the reference that I need. But the problem is that my document compiles with error. It's an error, not a warning. The auxiliary files also exist but still I get this error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is it a real error or a warning 'only'?

Comment: the other document must have an auxiliary file `otherdoc.aux`. I f it doesn't exist then run first LaTeX on this other document to create it.

Comment: It's an error, not a warning. the auxiliary file also exists but still I get this error. If there is another way, please instruct me.

Comment: Instead of “answering” your own (?!) question, you should comment on other user's comments or edit the original question to include the additional information.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. You've tagged it `cross-referencing` but the question itself mentions using **xcite** which has nothing to do with cross-referencing, and the text asks how to `cite a reference from another document`. `reference` is ambiguous, but `cite` suggests bibliographical citations rather than cross-references, although it isn't entirely clear. Note that **xcite** uses citation keys i.e. bibliographical references. If you really want to cross-reference a place in the other document marked by `\label{}` then you should use **xr** instead.

Comment: I came across this question when searching for my own problem. Using the package xcite to get the same citations that are in a different document results in a compilation error. The solution in my case was to also include the citation package that the original document was using (in my case natbib). Hopefully this helps someone else.